# Доступ по ssh с другой машины

Tags: git, bitbucket

Всем привет, есть удаленный репозиторий на **bitbucket**, на одной из машин я сгенерировал `ssh` ключ и добавил его в ssh секцию **битбакета**.

Проблемы в следующем:

- Добавляя `ssh` ключ, сгенерированный на другой машине, в **битбакет**, я ожидаю иметь такой же доступ к репозиторию, как и для первой машины. Но сделать clone проекта по ssh не удается;
- Добавляя оригинальный `ssh` ключ *id_rsa.pub* c одной машины на другую, я предполагаю, что буду иметь одинаковый доступ к **битбакету**. То есть для репозитория работа на разных машинах должна выглядеть как с одной.

Ошибка для этих двух случаев одна:

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

and the repository exists.

Мне нужно иметь доступ к репозиторию с разных компьютеров. Как решить проблему?

Comment: `id_rsa.pub` — судя по названию, это публичная, несекретная часть ключа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH использует [**асимметричное шифрование**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BC). Это значит, что ключ состоит из двух частей:

- Открытой (публичной) — для **зашифровки**.
- Закрытой (приватной) — для **расшифровки**.

`id_rsa.pub` это открытая часть ключа. Она не секретна, её можно распространять даже на публику, всем, кому нужно идентифицировать, что подключаетесь **именно вы** (предполагая, что ключ только ваш и он не скомпрометирован). Например, Bitbucket'у. Наличие содержимого этого файла *не позволяет* залогиниться от вашего имени.

Но есть ещё и `id_rsa` (в той же папке, рядом) с **закрытой** частью. Чтобы пройти проверку на совпадение открытого ключа, вам нужна именно она. Она исполняет роль пароля, но гораздо (на порядки, до практической бессмысленности) устойчевее к перебору.

Comment: спасибо с id_rsa и id_rsa.pub конект работает